# Anylogic - tank liquid color

Tags: anylogic

How can I change storage tank liquid color dynamically in the animation? For example, I would to change the color from red to blue when a new batch added in.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnyLogic does that for you as long as you specify a batch color when it is created in the FluidSource:
[image]

So define different batch colors and you will see them animated for you :)